# Cold air coming out from intake after A/C turns off

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air

When my A/C compressor turns off, the air handler seems to go into an almost idle state where it still sounds like it’s on but not running on full power. During this time, cold air is constantly blowing out of the intake vent which is near the front door. As a result it’s freezing my tile. Any ideas what might cause this? It’s a single unit, 4 ton Ruud Rheem, and air handler is also Rheem.

Comment: That is your Thermostat doing. What model is it

Comment: It's vaguely possible that a wiring problem causes the fan motor to run (slowly) in reverse.

Comment: It's not likely the air handler is running in "reverse", most all fans are squirrel cage designs which would hardly move any air in reverse.  What's more likely is there is something else creating negative pressure in the house:  Maybe a stove hood running or bathroom exhaust fans or even a HRV unit (heat recovery ventilation) unit that needs servicing.   The easiest way to start the diagnostic process is to turn off the breaker supplying power to the air handler and see if it stops. If so, something is going on with the thermostat but more likely the air handler itself. ... continued:

Comment: Next, check your thermostat and see if it's fan setting is set to "circ" or "fan on" (exact term will vary by thermostat.  Many air handlers have multiple speeds.  circ (circulation), is slower.  When using A/C it generally runs the AH at full speed.

Comment: I have just changed thermostats. I had a basic one before and now got the Nest. I've had the same issue with both thermostats. The thermostat indicates the air conditioning is off, but the air handler seems to be "idling" and pushing cold air from the intake vent.

Answer (score 1):

That is rare situation to have cold air coming from Air-Return (Intake).

Cold air would have to come in reverse direction true the air handler.

Unless you air handler fan is somehow miss-wired and running in opposite direction.

However it would be normal to have the fan running for ~15 minutes after the compressor is turned off to remove the cold from the coil.

If the fan is running as it should but all HVAC Dampers are closed, that could happen that air comes back since there is no exit for it.